# How to change title of cygwin windows?

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin

I am using ssh in cygwin and it has window title format: `username@hostname: /pwd`

Problem is when I have many ssh sessions I can't distinguish them because I can only see `username...` in taskbar.

Is there a way to display only hostname in title?

Comment: see https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Changing_bash_prompt TITLEBAR portion

Answer (score 1):

This is a more succinct way to do it, without messing with PS1. You could add this to your .bashrc or .bash_profile:

```
echo -e "\033]0; $(hostname) \007"
```